# Rotate left elements in an array with complexity O(n) and time O(1)

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I am trying to solve the problem of rotating elements inside an array to the left. Example: `array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` if I call the function `rotateToLeft(array[],int numberElements,int count)` where: `array` is the array to rotate, `numberElements` is the number of elements to rotate to the left and `count` is the size of the array. I am looking for a O(n) complexity and O(1) time consuming algorithm. My first solution is to use a doubly linked list, but I would like to know if there is a better solution.

Class Node of the linkedlist

```
    @interface Node : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic,assign) int element;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) Node* next;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) Node* previous;

    @end
```

Class to manage the linkedlist

```
    @interface LinkedList : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic,strong) Node* tail;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) Node* root;

   -(void)addNode:(int)value;
   -(void)printList;
   -(void)rotateLeftElementsOnList:(LinkedList*)list elements:(int)numElement;

   @end

   @implementation LinkedList

    -(instancetype)init{
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            self.tail = nil;
        }
        return self;

    }

    -(void)addNode:(int)value{
        Node* newNode = [[Node alloc] init];
        newNode.element = value;
        newNode.previous = nil;
        newNode.next = nil;
        if (self.tail == nil) {
            newNode.next = nil;
            newNode.previous = nil;
            self.tail = newNode;
            self.root = newNode;
            return;

        }
        self.tail.previous = newNode;
        newNode.next = self.tail;
        self.tail = newNode;   
    }

    -(void)printList{
        Node* header = self.root;
        while(header.previous != nil){
            NSLog(@"%d",header.element);
            header = header.previous;

        }
        NSLog(@"%d",header.element);
    }
```

/////This is my function to rotate elements an it works but I would like to know if some one knows a better solution,

```
    -(void)rotateLeftElementsOnList:(LinkedList*)list elements:(int)numElement{
        Node* header = self.root;
        int index = 0;
        while(index < numElement){
        header = header.previous;
        index++;

    }
        header.next.previous = nil;
        header.next = nil;
        self.root.next = self.tail;
        self.tail.previous = self.root;
        self.root = header;

    }
```

Comment: Do you perhaps mean O(n) **time** and O(1) **space**. Shifting all elements in a normal array in O(1) time is impossible and "complexity" can refer to either time or space.

Comment: Can you include example arguments for the function with corresponding output in your example as well?

Answer (score 2):

A linked list is an O(n) derivative of an array.  So that's the floor on this idea.  If you're ok transforming to a list, transform to one that's a ring, with the last node's next pointer pointing to the head.  Keep track of just a head pointer.  With that, a shift can be accomplished simply by advancing the head pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know objective-c, so I can't offer you a code. But here is an idea. Instead of shifting the array, you can create a class, which will have 2 properties: `a` of type `list/array` and `shift` of type `int`. After that, you will have method `get_element(int i)` which will get the `i-th` element using the `shift` value. A pseudo code would look something like this:

```
class ShiftedArray:
    int[] a
    int shift

    void shift_array(int positions):
        shift = positions

    int get_element(int i):
        return a[(n + i - shift % n) % n]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Objective-C, so unfortunately, I can't provide you the code snippet; but I'll explain you the logic:

1. Reverse the first `count` number of elements;
2. Reverse the remaining elements;
3. Reverse the entire array now.

Example:
Array is: `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]` and you want to shift by, say, 3 places:

1. Step 1:  `[3 2 1 4 5 6 7 8]`
2. Step 2:  `[3 2 1 8 7 6 5 4]`
3. Step 3:  `[4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3]`

The time complexity is `O(n)` since you just traverse the elements once to reverse them and the space complexity is `O(1)` since you are not using any additional auxiliary storage space.  Hope this is helpful!